# Cron job multi-tasks

Tags: cron

I want to write a cron job that do the following task:

Every one hour:

1) open an url, for example http://my.domain.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=1&action=edit (There is login ID and password) (The url is a Wordpress draft)

2)Enter the ID and password to log-in

3) Press "Save Draft" button

This will be very helpful for me since I have several actions associated with the "save draft" button

Answer (score 0):

Make the cron job do what clicking the 'save draft' button does. I cannot see any reason to go through the UI.

Comment: Hi Mitch, could you suggest me how to write a cron job to do the task? Since i read a lot of cron jobs tutorial, but cannot find any related stuff that can help me. Thank you very much!

Comment: I meant, making cron jobs to do those tasks is extremely complicated. Is it possible to go with the UI? I just feel that it is relatively simpler for me.

Comment: Your hosting provider should provide you with a way of setting up cron jobs. As for the file the cron job runs, that can be just a normal PHP file.